# Setting "More Navigation Controller's" titleView text

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm surprised that not "more" has been asked about this :-)

My app is a standard tab bar controller with multiple sections. Each section (tab) contains a navigation controller that controls a couple of view controllers (your basic tableview + detailview type of setup). Now that I've added a 6th tab, iOS creates the default "More" tab that controls the final two tabs. I need to eliminate the "More" text in the *middle* of the navigation bar (Note: Not the button text, nor the title of the tab itself), and apply a custom background image to the navigation bar.

**Note: This question is about customizing the "More" navigation bar - I've successfully modified the background image and titleView text on all of the non-iOS created navigation bars.**

In my app delegate, the app is put together thusly:

**Create View Controllers:**

```
ViewController1 *vc1 = [ViewController1 alloc] initWithNibName@"View1" bundle:nil];
vc1.title = @"VC1";
vc1.tabBarImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"];
```

Repeat the above routine 5 more times for view controllers vc2 through vc6.

**Create the individual navigation controllers:**

```
UINavigationController *nc1 = [UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc1];
```

Repeat 5 more times for nav controllers nc2 - nc6.

**Add Nav Controllers to Tab Bar Controller**

```
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: vc1, vc2, vc3, vc4, vc5, vc6, nil];
```

**All of the code above works perfectly. No issues.**

I then add a custom background image to the More navigation controller thusly:

```
    if (self.tabBarController.moreNavigationController){
        if ([self.tabBarController.moreNavigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)] ) {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navlogo.png"];
            [self.tabBarController.moreNavigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        } else {
            UINavigationBar *navbar = self.tabBarController.moreNavigationController.navigationBar;
            UIImage *headerImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navlogo.png"];
            [navbar setBackgroundImage:headerImg forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        }       
    }
```

**This too works just fine. No issues**

Since my custom background contains the client's logo dead center, I need to remove the text of the titleView that by default reads "More". Note, I'm not talking about the text of the Navigation BUTTON, but the label in the middle of the navigation bar.

Logically, one would assume that this would work:

```
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label.text = @"";
    self.tabBarController.moreNavigationController.navigationItem.titleView = label;
```

...because I do this in all of individual view controllers, substituting self.navigationItem.titleView for self.tabBarController.moreNavigationController, etc.

But this doesn't work! I can successfully change both the background image and the titleView text on all of my navigation controllers with this exact same code (again, substituting self.navigationController.navigationItem for the moreNavController stuff...). However, in the app delegate, I can only set the background image, but not the titleView of the More nav controller.

Any solutions would be greatly appreciated.

VB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, my original code was correct, just in the wrong place.

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label.text = @"";
self.tabBarController.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.topItem.titleView = label;
```

However, I was previously executing this *before* I added the tabBarController as my rootViewController

The correct order is:

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label.text = @"";
self.tabBarController.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.topItem.titleView = label;
```

Answer (score 1):

Posting Swift5 version as it took me quite some time to make it work properly

```
moreNavigationController.viewControllers[0].tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "My Title", image: UIImage(named: "MoreTab")!, tag: 1111)
moreNavigationController.navigationBar.topItem!.title = "My Title"
```

Please note that changing moreNavigationController.tabBarItem doesn't work quite well. I do this in viewDidLoad() of a class which extends UITabBarController

Comment: Great answer! This worked with simply setting a new `UITabBarItem`. Here's my version with a `navigationController` embedded in a `UITabBarController`:

`navigationController?.tabBarController?.moreNavigationController.viewControllers.first?.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "My Title", image: nil, selectedImage: nil)`

Answer (score 0):

E.g., in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: of the Tab Controller iOS Template

```
// Override point for customization after application launch.

UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)(self.window.rootViewController);
UINavigationController *moreNavigationController = tabBarController.moreNavigationController;
moreNavigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"";
```

This changes the navigation bar title, but leaves the tab label title as "More".

Comment: Thanks again for the reply. Your solution does in fact eliminate the title from the top of the nav bar while leaving the tab title intact; however, it has the unfortunate side-effect of nuking the back-buttons on the nav controllers that are contained within the More Nav Controller. I'll keep digging and hopefully post the complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found one

**Swift 2.2**

Put this in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**

```
tabBarCtr.moreNavigationController.delegate = self
tabBarController.moreNavigationController.viewControllers.first?.title = ""
```

Implement this delegate method

```
func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, willShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool)
    {
        navigationController.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItems = nil
        navigationController.viewControllers.first?.title = ""

    }
```

**This will also remove the edit button** on top of more navigation controller navigation bar.

Answer (score -1):

This might not be applicable to everyone on the thread but for me... I had a tabBarController with > 5 items... I needed to set the title on the automatically generated moreNavigationController... it was as simple as specifying self.title=@"title" in the viewDidLoad method of the target detailviewcontroller.

Answer (score -3):

You can change the title inside the viewDidLoad function

```
self.title = @""
```

Comment: denil, your reply is incorrect for several reasons: First, my original post has nothing to do with setting properties of the view controllers that I've created, but rather, the iOS-created view controller. My post was unambiguous in that respect. Secondly, setting the self.title property eliminates the title on not only the Nav Bar label, but also the tab and back button. I would encourage you to read the questions more carefully before tossing out incorrect and misleading answers. Your post should be down-voted by those with enough points to do so, as it is clearly incorrect.